# Selecting options by importing Excel sheet on CommCare

Tags: commcare

We have a list of respondents from our baseline survey along with basic information on an Excel sheet. I need to bulk upload this list on CommCare for the ease of doing an endline survey so that surveyor can simply choose which one to continue with.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to upload each of those as their own case? If so, you can use the Case Importer to upload them all from Excel:

https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Importing+Cases+Using+Excel